# Loosing my Vagrant box

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox

Before I shut down my pc, I suspend my Vagrant box.

When I power my PC on again, my Vagrant box is still suspended in the VirtualBox Panel and the config files under ".vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox" are there.

When I want to power my box up again or even do a "vagrant status", the box gets shut down and all the config files under ".vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox" are gone.

I have to manualy generate the "id" file to get it back online.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you controlling your Vagrant box only thru the vagrant command line? Or also through the VirtualBox UI? I found Vagrant can get confused if you do both. Also, which version of Vagrant are you on, and what is the host OS? (I assume some version of Windows?)

Comment: I use the commandline. My Vagrant Version is 1.6.3 and my Virtual Box version is 4.3.14.